# Combining two buffers into one

Tags: c, embedded, buffer, buffer-overflow

I need to have two buffers (`A` and `B`) and when either of the buffers is full it needs to write its contents to the "merged" buffer - `C`. Using memcopy seems to be too slow for this operation as noted below in my question. Any insight?'

I haven't tried but I've been told that memcopy will not work. This is an embedded system. 2 buffers. Both of different sizes and when they are full dumb to a common 'C' buffer which is a bigger size than the other two.. Not sure why I got down rated..

**Edit:** Buffer A and B will be written to prior to C being completely empty.

The **memcopy** is taking too long and the common buffer 'C' is getting over run.

Comment: Does the merged buffer need to be a copy of the data or can the buffer refer to other buffers.

Comment: How are they to be merged?  Are all three fixed sizes?  Can buffer `C` be a C++ class?  Will buffer `A` be written to before `C` is emptied?

Comment: You should probably remove the `C++` tag, you are not going to like the answers this gets you.

Comment: Show us what you tried, and what problems you encountered.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Ha you had my exact same edit at the exact same time :)

Comment: How are you going to copy data without `memcpy`?

Comment: Double buffering, dude. Flip a pointer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `REP MOVS` IIRC

Comment: @ rerun, the buffer needs to be exactly what was in the 'A' or 'B' buffer

Comment: @ MooningDuck I guess it could be a class? Yes Buffer A and B will be written to prior to C being completely empty.

Comment: The only way you can merge two buffers without memcpy is by linking them, like a linked list of buffer fragments (or an array of fragments). If the buffer must be contiguous, you could reserve a large address space and commit it on demand. On Win32 the `VirtualAlloc` function can do that. This gives you a very large contiguous buffer, of which only a portion is allocated. Later you can allocate further pages as the buffer needs to grow.

Comment: @tamas, I like this idea but this is an embedded system not to be on a PC unfortunately :/. I only have limited memory i.e. 5k bytes and other stuff is going on as well

Comment: "I haven't tried but I've been told that memcopy will not work" - This is a bad attitude to have as a programmer. First, you seem to have dropped an awful lot of significant information. (Certainly using `memcpy` into a third buffer would "work" for some sense of the word, so why does your co-worker object to your approach? Ask what they are thinking and for a specific suggestion.) Second, if someone tells you simply "that's no good" without being any more specific, they could of course be wrong, so one approach would be to implement it naively and see if it gives you satisfactory performance.

Comment: @ asveikau Because it is too slow. I've seen it and can verify... The copy is taking too long and the common buffer is getting over run. the end. Maybe I should have rephrased what I said above. Sry

Comment: @Questioneer - Looking at your reply to Tamas, it sounds like you might have to go maintaining non-sequential buffers with some kind of linking.

Comment: Question is can either of you give me a simple example of this? It would be much appreciated

Comment: Consider that a buffer may not always have to be contiguous. I've done a lot of work with 600dpi images (very large buffers). If you can break them up into a sequence of smaller fragments, it helps reduce fragmentation and copying due to buffer growth. In some cases buffers must be contiguous, if your API / microcontroller mandates it. For example Windows bitmap functions require continuity. You could try to use the C `realloc` function, but it could be `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free` internally. Either way `memcpy` is supposed to be the fastest possible way of copying contiguous buffers.

Comment: @ tamas, put that in an answer and i'll accept yours. You've been the most helpful. Thanks

Comment: How big are the buffers (a few bytes, a few kilobytes, a few megabytes…)? Do you have an MMU? Can you change the interface of the code that reads from buffer C if required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way you can merge two buffers without `memcpy` is by linking them, like a linked list of buffer fragments (or an array of fragments).

Consider that a buffer may not always have to be contiguous. I've done a lot of work with 600dpi images, which means very large buffers. If you can break them up into a sequence of smaller fragments, that helps reducing fragmentation as well as unnecessary copying due to buffer growth.

In some cases buffers must be contiguous, if your API / microcontroller mandates it. For example, Windows bitmap functions require continuity. You could try to use the C `realloc` function, but it might internally work like the combination of `malloc`+`memcpy`+`free`. Either way, as others have said earlier, `memcpy` is supposed to be the fastest possible way of copying contiguous buffers.

If the buffer must be contiguous, you could reserve a large address space and commit it on demand. The implementation depends on the platform. For example, on Win32 the `VirtualAlloc` function can do that. This gives you a very large contiguous buffer, of which only a portion is allocated (committed). Later you can commit further pages as the buffer needs to grow. This trick requires the concept of virtual memory, which may not be available on a microcontroller.

Answer (score 9):

memcpy is pretty much the fastest way to copy memory. It's frequently a compiler intrinsic and is highly optimized. If it's too slow you're probably going to have to find another way to speed your program up.

I'd expect that copying memory faster is not the lowest hanging fruit in a program.

Some other opportunities could be to copy less memory or copy less often. See if you can profile your program to analyze it's performance and find where the biggest opportunities are.

Edit: With your edit it sounds like the problem is that there's not enough time for you to deal with some data all at once between the time you notice that it needs to be handled and the time that more data comes in. A solution in this case could be, as one of the commenters noted, to have additional buffers that you can flip between. So you may then have time to handle the data in one while another is filled up.